# Can't center a div after using the flex box layout

Tags: html, flexbox, centering, box

I guess, I am doing something rather trivial completely wrong.
I am rather new in CSS and HTML and trying to use a centered TEXT and image on the top of webpage
I succeeded using the flex box container layout using 3 boxes
But I am unable to get the next div centered below the flex box.
All other lines are centering under the 3rd box of the flex box container ..??

check my code and output
https://codepen.io/alex1965/pen/eYZLQQG

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello Jtronicx</title>
<style>
    /*default version*/
    @font-face {
        font-family:"Jtronicxfont";
        src: url("fonts/alien-encounters-regular.ttf");
        font-weight:normal;
              }
    /*bold version*/
    @font-face {
        font-family:"Jtronicxfont";
        src: url("fonts/alien-encounters-bold.ttf");
        font-weight:bold;       
              }
    body {
        background-color: black;
    }
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: black;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
   }
#company{
        color: DarkKhaki;
        text-align: center;
        font-family:"Jtronicxfont";
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size:90px;
        margin-bottom:2px;
        }
a:link, a:visited {
        text-decoration: none;
    background-color: rgb(38, 31, 5);
    color: DarkKhaki;  
    font-family:"Jtronicxfont";
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size: 130%;
    text-align: center;
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(117, 104, 50);
    border-radius: 13px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
  }
a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(45, 37, 5);
    color: Khaki;
    cursor:pointer;
    }

div {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    color:DarkKhaki;
    font-family:"Arial";
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size:20px;     
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div></div>
        <div id="company" style="flex-basis: 600px">Jtronicx bv</div>
        <div><img src="jtronicx.jpg" width="80" height="70"><div>  
    </div>
    <div class="offerings">
        <div>industrial business development</div>
        <div>proof of concepts</div>
        <div>electronics integration</div>
        <div>web design</div>
    <div>   
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.jtronicx.com">Company</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.jtronicx.com">What I offer</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.jtronicx.com">Projects</a></li>
    <Li><a href="http://www.jtronicx.com">Contact</a></Li>
</ul>   
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is you are using `<div>` tags where a closing `</div>` is expected.

[image]

Comment: Hi Francisco... Well it is solved. And I was looking to my code for over 1 hour... OMG how stupid! THANKS!!!!